# RadioButtonFor getting its id instead of value

Tags: c#, razor, radio-button

So I have a model, Client, which references to a key of another model, Title.

The title has the following property :

```
string Id;
string value;
```

and my model is like this :

```
int id
string title (id of model title)
*some other property*
```

before displaying my view, I am getting data from my database for the title:

```
List<Title> listTitle = GetTitles();
```

and then passing the list in a viewBag:

```
ViewBag.TitleList = listTitle;
```

My view is as follows:

```
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
                    @foreach (String val in ViewBag.TitleList)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Title, val)
                    }
                </div>
```

Here I am stuck, I want to display the value for the radio button but get the id of the selected radio button when the view is submitted.

How do I do this?

Comment: The Title list contains 2 properties "Id,Title", why you dont update your foreach to use the Title object instead of string.

Comment: Yes but my view already has a view model which contains a key to model title.

Comment: As per your code `ViewBag.TitleList` is type of `List<Title>`. I'm not sure how this code `@foreach (String val in ViewBag.TitleList)` can work for you?